# Symfony2 + AngularJS allow route

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, symfony, web

I have a Symfony2 project with this structure (included angularjs project):

```
Project (Symofony2)
  |_ app
  |_ ...
  |_ src
  |   |_ Bundle
  |        |_ Resources
  |             |_ Views
  |                  |_ template.html.twig 
  |_ web
      |_ public
      |_ app.php
      |_ app_dev.php
      |_ project_angularjs (AngularJS working project)
```

My AngularJS project have this URL to execute the project:
    http://v/Project/web/project_angularjs/#/ad/0
(`#/ad/0` --> Are parameters)

And my template.html.twig have this code:

```
<iframe src="http://v/Project/web/project_angularjs/#/ad/0">
</iframe>
```

But only it's working when i send this (without parameters and specifying the index.html):
    http://v/Project/web/project_angularjs/index.html

```
<iframe src="http://v/Project/web/project_angularjs/index.html">
</iframe>
```

When I execute the first URL have a "Forbidden" error and when execute the second have the page but without parameters... I'm trying to allow this route in .htaccess in /web folder but unsuccessfully.

How can I allow the params and this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this error I update my .htaccess file of web folder:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html #app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine Off #On
    ...
</IfModule>
```